# How to disable people picker field from InfoPath 2013 of SharePoint List?

Tags: infopath

When I set formatting rule to disable this control, it is not disabled actually and I can add peoples in it and save it.

please help.

[image]

Comment: How u disabled people picker? Using conditional formatting?

Comment: Make sure you are using IE. Chrome and Firefox do not make the box disabled.

Comment: @Vishal yes i am using condition formatting and chose "disable this control".

Comment: @AhmadZia but we use all browser(ie, chrome n firefox). Do you know this solution for chrome and firefox as well??

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in infopath people picker control. Infopath disables the people picker fully only in IE but in chrome and firefox, the textbox of people picker allows us to enter users  OR alter old values. Very strange.

But as a workaround you can do two things,

**For New Item Form:**

If you dont want to allow users to enter values in people picker then its better to hide it completely. You can do it using same way with conditional formatting.

[image]

**For EDIT/View Item Form:**

If you only want to show old values then you can use calculated values control to show people or group field in infopath.

Add a Calculated Value from the Controls--> Control properties
-->select Insert field or Group-->  Show advanced view--> Expand DataFields-->Expand people column --->Select Display Name.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Vishal for this work around and I already tried it but one thing is not meet for me that is, I have Test People(people picker) Field, which is multiple user field where I have more than one peoples added. And I tried to add calculated field but it only displays first one people, other people are not displaying in display form. for example if Test People field have 2 users added then calculated value shows only one.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Create a new text box and add "DisplayName" using the Text box properties. You hide control on the original person/group box while display new text box as "Disable". This is workaround method.